# ubuntu 14.04.1 mounts /dev/sda1 and asks to unmount while partitioning

Tags: partitioning, mount, debian-installer

We have been making custom made initrd.gz generated through debian-installer for 10.04 and 12.04 ubuntu.

We have been partitioning the disk and have made it automated completely and ask user to answer only few questions.

The problem I am facing is as below:

==========================================

You have mounted partition on /dev/sda

Would you like the installer to unmount it

===========================================

In 14.04.1 ISO /dev/sda1 is mounted on to /media and doesn't get unmounted even if I use preseed/early_command string umount /media
I have tried all options of umount –l –f

Due to this a user has one more question to answer.

Neither does partman/unmount_active boolean true work

Earlier in 12.04, It would not ask to unmount the disk as /dev/sda1 was never mounted to media.

Is there a solution to either unmount the disk or set the Boolean as true through preseed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [bug 1347726](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1347726) which has not yet been resolved.

So I guess the answer, as of mid 2016, is: No.